# Return only when condition is true (without using if)

Tags: c#

I was asking myself if there is a possibility to use `return` in a method that only gets executed if a condition is true but without using an `if` statement. If the condition is false, nothing would be returned.

For better understanding:

```
public bool MyMethod()
{
    if (HasErrors())
        return HasErrors();

    // Some more code
}
```

`Some more code` would then also return something. I now thought of something like this:

```
public bool MyMethod()
{
    return HasErrorsButReturnsOnlyIfTrue();

    // Some more code
}
```

But `return HasErrorsButReturnsOnlyIfTrue();` only has to be executed if `HasErrors()` returns true. Otherwise it would be skipped.

Is there any possibility to achieve something like that without using `if`?

Comment: Without `if`? No. Without calling the method twice? Yes: `if (hasErrors()) return true;`

Comment: @Dennis_E `return hasErrors()`. Why would you do `if (true) return true` ?

Comment: @GuillaumeBeauvois He doesn't want to return if it's false.

Comment: Throw might be an option.

Comment: In such case, when you dont want the method to return anything, what do you expect to be found in the returning object??

Comment: @SamGhatak It's just an example. I could have chosen anything to return. I just want to know if there's a possibility to achieve this.

Comment: oh!!! so basically "Otherwise it would be skipped" this is something confusing...so, you want to return something on condition without using a if block!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be the closest you'll get:

```
public bool MyMethod()
{
    return HasErrors()
        ? true
        : SomeMoreCode();
}
```

Note that this means you'll have to put your 'Some More Code' in a separate method, and that method must now also return a boolean.

Comment: Or even shorter: `return HasErrors() || SomeMoreCode();`

Comment: This doesn't solve: `only returns some value if a condition is true`, but that might not be what OP really wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: this is just a joke.

```
public bool MyMethod()
{
    try
    {
        return HasErrorsButReturnsOnlyIfTrue();
    }
    catch
    {
        // Some more code
        Console.WriteLine("Test");
        return false;
    }
}

public bool HasErrorsButReturnsOnlyIfTrue()
{
    if (some condition)
        return true;
    else
        throw new Exception();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a [nullable function](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-nullable-types/).

```
void bool? isBar()
{
    SomeObj someObj = check(); // Returns someObj;
    if (someObj == null)
        return false; // Nothing there
    else if (someObj.something == 1)
        return null; // It's there! Don't return!
    else
        return true; // Something's there, but not what we want
}

void doSth()
{
    bool? isValid = isBar();
    if (isValid != null)
        return (bool)isValid;
}
```

Alternately, the same could be done by making a struct or class that indicates whether to return or not.

```
struct Validator
{
    public bool ShouldReturn;
    public bool ReturnBool; // Could skip this and just make ShouldReturn nullable like the above example
    public string ErrMsg;
}
```